# Refresh current view iOS

Tags: ios, xcode, refresh, tableview, reload

I found lots of "reloadData" for TableView questions here, but my case is different.

I have a notification App, that uses UILocalNotification to fire reminders.

I need to refresh my tableview in real time after an alert fires, without the need of closing and opening the app to do so...

Example:

User is viewing the scheduled reminders (tableView), when suddenly one of the reminders fires. At this moment, the tableView will reload, but only if the user quits application or go back to another view and open the tableView again. That can't happen cause the application breaks if the user press the row in the tableView witch showed the current reminder (that's already completed and doesn't exists anymore).

I need to reload tableView in real time, without leaving the tableView Controller view. any idea on how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

When a local notification for your app fires while the app is in the foreground, the system sends the `application:didReceiveLocalNotification:` message to your app delegate. From there, you should notify the view controller (via a direct reference and message send or possibly with a custom `NSNotification`) to do whatever it needs to do in this case.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Right. I already implemented the reloadData in didReceiveLocalNotification, I implemented reloadData in all app delegates such as didEnterBackground, didEnterForeground, etc... I need to know what is the code line to refresh it in real time, since realodData isn't working (well, it is, but not as I want to ,lol...)

Comment: Or another solution would be to, for example, dealloc every view and pop to main view as soon as the notification fires in the foreground... Any suggestions?